# Passing texture map from user input to A-Frame Component

Tags: aframe

Got this thing working already with THREE.js and now want to add the same functionality to my A-Frame component. I have an user image input dialog and the below script runs when the image changes. The question is how do I pass this data through the component? Schema seems to modify the data somehow since the console.log output from inside the document versus component is different!

**In HTML document:**

`n {uuid: "6682DFA3-78C6-4BC6-9C5C-C2430A046D73", name: "", sourceFile: "", image: img, mipmaps: Array[0]…`

**Inside the component:**

`String {0: "e", 1: "m", 2: "p", 3: "t", 4: "y", 5: "T", 6: "e", 7: "x", 8: "t", 9: "u", 10: "r", 11: "e", uuid: "6682DFA3-78C6-4BC6-9C5C-C2430A046D73", name: "", sourceFile: "", image: img, mipmaps: Array[0]…`

```
$("#userImage").change(function () {
    var image = document.createElement( 'img' );
    var texture = new THREE.Texture( image );
    image.onload = function()  {
            texture.needsUpdate = true;
            // Helper is entity which has component with the shader
            helper.setAttribute('myComponent', {
                texture: texture
            });
        };

    userImage = $("#userImage")[0];
    if (userImage.files && userImage.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = function (e) {
            image.src = e.target.result;
        };

        reader.readAsDataURL(userImage.files[0]);
    }
});
```

var texture above returns similar data as var texture below.

```
var loader = new THREE.TextureLoader(manager);
var texture = loader.load( 'img/image.jpg' );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wish to pass just a big object, you can modify the schema to take JSON.

`js
AFRAME.registerComponent('foo', {
  schema: {
    parse: JSON.parse
  }
});`

Then you can pass in as JSON. Or if you do `.setAttribute`, A-Frame won't do parsing (`.setAttribute('foo', {yourData})`).